# Getting favoured child based on user inputted spending

Tags: java, input

```
System.out.println("What is the title of the book" + " " + childsName + " "+  "would like?"); 
bookWanted=keyboard.nextLine();
shoppingList +=bookWanted+"\n";

do {
    System.out.println("What is the price of" + " " + bookWanted); //Input for price of book wanted
    if (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
        bookPrice=keyboard.nextDouble();
        totalCost+=bookPrice;
        isNumber=true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid price"); //book price validation 
        isNumber=false;
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
} while(!isNumber);

keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Are you finished Y/N?");
answer=keyboard.nextLine();
if (answer.charAt(0)=='y'||answer.charAt(0)=='Y'){
    finished=true;
}
```

Can anyone help with this code it's nearly 100% there just one slight bit I'm struggling with. You enter the children's names and the books they want and the price of the books. Then based on the amount spent on each child you have to determine the favourite child. I can't grasp how to split the value for each child and keep that until it is exceeded any suggestions welcome thanks.

Comment: Post only the relevant code

Comment: Please refer to this: http://sscce.org/ when posting a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep only the highest total value or all the total values?

If you want to keep the highest total value you simply need two new variables: one which keeps track of the highest number and one which keeps track of who it was.
When somebody is entering more books and you find that their total is higher than the highest total, replace the highest total with this new total and store their name in the other variable.

If you would like to keep track of all totals you can use a HashMap or Collection of some kind for each name/value pair, then see which value is most at the end.

Comment: Just need the highest value and then need to match that to the child it was spent on.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (favoriteCost < totalCost){
    favoriteCost = totalCost;
    favoriteChild = childsName;
}
```

Use this code after the user specifies they are finished.  This will make sure that only the favorite child's name and the child's total cost are stored and none of the others.  You can then call them later with something like this:

```
System.out.println("The favorite child is: " + favoriteChild)
```

Comment: On review it's actually not quite there it's now storing the value of the last inputted as the favourite regardless of spend will tinker with it a bit!

Comment: Provided the if statement was done correctly, it should only store a new value if that child's total cost was larger.  You may want to check the variable scopes and maybe even make sure that the doubles you input are being compared properly